# Maintaining the jquery object in ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to maintain the datatable object in ajax call. Please refer below code

```
$(function(){
     function applyDataTables(options) {

          //datatable object
          var $datatable = $("#table1").dataTable(options);



          if (some condition) {
              this.dataTableObj = [];
              this.dataTableObj.push($datatable);
          } else { 
              $datatable = dataTableObj[0];
          }
    ...............................................
    }
})();
```

first time page load, it will call this function  and find some datatable object after that am making some ajax post that time also it will trigger the same function  and finding the datatable object.

so, i want to maintain the $datatable object when the page loaded first time, during some ajax posts i want to use this same object for other purpose how can i maintain the $datatable object in ajax post.

if i add that object to "this.dataTableObj" i can able to get the value of old object in ajax post.whether it is correct way of maintaining existing object in javascript.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well "this" always refers to calling object.
but if you call

```
 applyDataTables(options) //this will be window object;
```

and it can be overridden using call, apply or bind method

```
 applyDataTables.call(someObj,options) //this will point to someObj
```

In your function this can be confusing.
Plus if you are passing it to some callback this can be overriden by call or apply method.

So instead of storing datatableObj in this you can store it on some global namespacing whose scope will be on all ajax call.

You may define

```
var globV={
     dataTableObj:[]
};
```

//you can use different namespacing too instead of globV

```
$(function(){
     function applyDataTables(options) {

          //datatable object
          var $datatable = $("#table1").dataTable(options);



          if (some condition) {
              globV.dataTableObj = [];
              globV.dataTableObj.push($datatable);
          } else { 
              $datatable = globV.dataTableObj[0];
          }
    ...............................................
    }
})();
```